# Error using Jaybird and Android

Tags: android, database, jaybird

I created an application on android with Firebird direct wifi connect.
Sometimes I get this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error
>   occured while executing doInBackground() at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.iscDatabaseInfo(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:518)
>   at
>   org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractConnection.isValid(AbstractConnection.java:594)
>   at
>   br.com.controlemesa.banco.DBFBConnect.disconnect(DBFBConnect.java:61)
>   at
>   br.com.controlemesa.banco.DBFBConnect.spListaMesas(DBFBConnect.java:170)
>   at
>   br.com.controlemesa.activities.MesasActivity$PopulaGridMesas.doInBackground(MesasActivity.java:193)
>   at
>   br.com.controlemesa.activities.MesasActivity$PopulaGridMesas.doInBackground(MesasActivity.java:1)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306) ...
>   4 more

Has anyone else received this message? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code, this `NullPointerException` can occur if the connection was already closed. I have created issue [JDBC-313](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-313) in the Jaybird tracker. I will fix it in the 'normal' Jaybird for version 2.2.4. Usually the maintainer of the [Android Jaybird project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/androidjaybird/) will release a new version shortly after that.

Not knowing your exact code, I am not sure what a workaround is. As your stacktraces lists `DBFBConnect.disconnect`, I assume you want to disconnect. In that case I suggest you don't check for validity of the connection, but simply call `close()` on the connection.